# Parsing custom date with MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz format in android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, date-parsing

I have a string that represents a date with a format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` that looks like:

```
"03/26/2014 17:32:25 IST"<BR>
```

When I parse the string into a date as:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("03/26/2014 17:32:25 IST"));
String output = sdf.parse(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

I have tried adding `Locale.getDefault()` in the SimpleDateFormat but it didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this code?

Comment: You haven't described what your problem is. Please explain your expected output and how that deviates from your actual output.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention the exception that I'm getting while parsing the date. While parsing the date in Android using `sdf.Parse`, I get an exception as java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "03/26/2015 17:32:25 IST" (at offset 20). Any idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error: You try to case a `java.util.Date` (the result of parse-method) on `String` (compile-error).

Second error: You should use pattern symbol HH not hh (twenty-four-hour-clock according to hour input of 17h).

Third error: Set the timezone on the format object, not on Calendar (and it hopefully corresponds to timezone IST - either you are in Israel or in India).

**Updated:** It appears that "IST" is not a known time zone name on your Android device. The motivation of Google-Android was probably to avoid ambiguous names ("Israel Standard Time" or "India Standard Time") so Android has other different names in its resource repository. You might try text preprocessing like this workaround:

```
if (timestampText.endsWith(" IST")) {
  timestampText = timestampText.substring(0, timestampText.length() - 4);
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
java.util.Date d = sdf.parse(timestampText);
```

Also check the output of method `DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getZoneStrings()` in order to see if Android expects another timezone name instead of "IST" (which is more wide spread on Java-VMs).

Comment: Thanks Meno. It worked. I never thought of "Israel Standard Time" or "India Standard Time".

Comment: @Manish Am just curious, what does following code output on your device? `System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata").getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.getDefault()));`

Comment: The output is GMT+05:30. Which doesn't make sense if you are asking it to give `TimeZone.SHORT`. This is the reason I had to write my own logic to get IST with the DateTime.

Comment: @Manish That is the explanation. On my PC I get "IST", you get "GMT+05:30". Therefore your parser cannot interprete "IST" which is not stored in android resources for what ever reason.

Comment: @Manish Please consider accepting this answer if it helped solve your problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try Below code you need to assign output into Date data type : 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse("03/26/2014 17:32:25 IST"));
    java.util.Date output = sdf.parse(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thanks Neha. But even tough if the output type is date, Android will through parsing error
`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "03/26/2015 17:32:25 IST" (at offset 20)`

Comment: Try with SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

umm, something like this? Make sure you are using proper imports..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
        Date parse = null;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            parse = sdf.parse("03/26/2014 17:32:25 IST");
            calendar.setTime(parse);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, calendar.getTime() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, check imports, try rebuild project, checkout imports

Comment: Imports are good. but even then getting the same error.
This code works on a Micromax Android phone but does't work on Samsung Galaxy tab 2. What can be the glitch here??

Comment: @Manish The resource repositories of different android devices are not necessarily the same and can yield different time zone names (very unfortunately - this shows how unreliable zone names are).

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String date_parse="2015-04-09 05:06:14";
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = sdfSource.parse(date_parse);

        SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
        date_parse = sdfDestination.format(date);

        System.out.println("Date is converted from dd/MM/yy format to MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
        System.out.println("Converted date is : " + date_parse);

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

output:
Date is converted from dd/MM/yy format to MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a
Converted date is : April 09,2015 05:06 AM